# upgrading array store on combo box from 4.07 to 4.1

Tags: extjs4.1

The below configuration works on 4.07 but not 4.1.

On 4.1 i can see that my combo has 3 items. It just doesn't reader the displayField and valueField.

i'm using the mvc architecture.

In my view

```
{
xtype: 'combobox',
id: 'ProofRequired',
name: 'ProofRequired',
fieldLabel: 'Proof Required',
displayField: 'Name',
store: 'ProofRequired',
triggerAction: 'all',
queryMode: 'local',
valueField: 'Id'
},
```

in my app.js

```
stores: [ 'VarnishType'],
```

and my store

```
Ext.define('Mis.store.ProofRequired', {    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',


    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: true,
            storeId: 'ProofRequired',
            clearOnPageLoad: false,
            data: [
                {
                    Id: '1',
                    Name: 'Digital'
                },
                {
                    Id : '2',
                    Name : 'PDF'
                },
                {
                    Id : '3',
                    Name : 'Other'
                }
            ],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                reader: {
                    type: 'array'
                }
            },
            fields: [
                {
                    Id: 'Id',
                    Name: 'Name'
                }
            ]
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you see in the network trafic? Do you see JSON data coming back to your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below worked for me. I'm 100% sure why. I believe i need to put quotes around the field names.

```
Ext.define('Mis.store.ProofRequired', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        autoLoad: true,
        storeId: 'ProofRequired',
        clearOnPageLoad: false,
        fields: ['Id', 'Name'],
        data : [
            {"Id":"1", "Name":"Digital"},
            {"Id":"2", "Name":"PDF"},
            {"Id":"3", "Name":"Other"}
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            reader: {
                type: 'array'
            }
        }
    }, cfg)]);
}
```

});